# Glassfish 4.0 with Java 9

Tags: java, netbeans-8, glassfish-4

Recently we started working on technology upgrade of our system and would like to know if Java 9.0 supported for Glassfish 4.0.

Also I wanted to know if Netbeans 8.X version is having support on Java 9. If so how to configure Java in netbeans? As I see, when I try to configure Java 9, I could not see any jar files loaded.

Please suggest me how to configure Java 9 with Glassfish 4.0 and NetBeans 8.x (To be precise, I am using Netbeans 8.0.2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> would like to know if Java 9.0 supported for Glassfish 4.0.

Yes, the current version of Glassfish 4.x (4.1.2) will run web applications built using Java 9.

> I wanted to know if Netbeans 8.X version is having support on Java 9.

Definitely not. NetBeans 8.x only supports **JDK 8** and earlier.

> Please suggest me how to configure Java 9 with Glassfish 4.0 and
>   NetBeans 8.x

As mentioned above, you can't use Java 9 with NetBeans 8.x so discard that option. But you can build Java 9 web apps that run on Glassfish 4.x using NetBeans 9 Beta. To do that:

- Download and install **JDK 9**.
- [Download and unzip Glassfish 4.1.2](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/glassfish-412-released)
- [Download and unzip Apache NetBeans 9 Beta](https://builds.apache.org/job/incubator-netbeans-linux/398/).
- Start *Apache NetBeans 9 Beta* by running **netbeans64.exe** (or **netbeans.exe** on 32-bit).
- Select **Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins** and install everything with a **Category** of **Java Web and EE**. NetBeans will restart.
- Select **Tools -> Java Platforms** to add **JDK 9** as a platform (as shown in the OP).
- Select the **Services** tab, right click on the **Servers** node and select **Add Server...** from the popup menu.
- In the **Add Server Instance** wizard select **Glassfish Server** and click the **Browse...** button to navigate to your unzipped installation of Glassfish 4.1.2.
- From the **Services** tab start the Glassfish server you just added, and then go to http://localhost:8080 in a broswer to verify that Glassfish 4.1.2 is running OK.
- Use the **File -> New Project... -> Java Web -> Web Application** wizard to create a simple web application that is configured to run on the Glassfish server you just added.
- In the **Projects** panel select your web project, right click and select **Properties**.
- Select **Libraries** from the **Categories** list and set **Java Platform** to **JDK 9**.
- Select **Sources** from the **Categories** list and set **Source/Binary Format** to **JDK 9**. Click **OK**.
- In the **Projects** panel select the web project, right click and select **Run**. The page for your **JDK 9** web app should open in the default browser.

Notes:

- You can install and use **JDK 10** instead of **JDK 9** (or as well as **JDK 9**) on NetBeans 9 Beta.
- You can freely run NetBeans 9 Beta concurrently with an existing installation of NetBeans 8.x. They are completely separate and will not impact each other.
- Use the latest version of Glassfish (currently 4.1.2) rather than version 4.0 since a lot of bugs have been fixed.
- Go to the [Apache Netbeans 9 Beta web site](https://netbeans.apache.org/) for more details.